# CSS / HTML IE 7 problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am having trouble getting something working in IE 7, works fine in all other browsers, but if you take a look at http://jamessuske.com/thornwood2/ in IE 7 you will notice two gaps inbetween the topCotent and the contentArea and the other gap between contentArea and contentBottom.

No idea on how to fix this.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="topContent">
<img src="images/top.gif" width="1009" height="37" border="0" />
</div><!--topContent-->

<div class="leftContent">
<img src="images/leftSide.gif" width="48" height="494" border="0" />
</div><!--leftContent-->

<div class="contentArea">

</div><!--contentArea-->

<div class="rightContent">
<img src="images/rightSide.gif" width="49" height="494" border="0" />
</div><!--rightContent-->

<div class="bottomContent">
<img src="images/bottom.gif" width="1009" height="39" border="0" />
</div><!--bottomContent-->
```

CSS CODE

```
.topContent{
width:1009px;
}

.leftContent{
float:left;
}

.contentArea{
background:#FFF;
width:912px;
min-height:494px;
float:left;
}

.rightContent{
float:right;
}

.bottomContent{
width:1009px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add height to the classes as shown below which will fix ur issue for IE7

```
.topContent{
  width:1009px;
  *height:37px;
}

.leftContent{
  float:left;
  *height:494px;
}


.rightContent{
  float:right;
  *height:494px;
}
```

Comment: @user979331 I think all you need to do to get it to work for other browsers is take out the asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

The `<img>` element is an inline element. That means that it has a `vertical-align` property that, by default, is set to `bottom`. For some reason, this causes problems when you just have an `<img>` contained by a block-level element (like a `<div>`).

That's where your gaps are coming from: For some reason, IE adds a little bit of space to the bottom of the `<div>` elements that contain those images. (It's also doing this to your `.bottomContent` element; that's just harder to notice/not as big a deal.)

The fix is as simple as this:

```
.topContent img, .leftContent img, .contentArea img, .rightContent img {
    display:block
}
```

(If, for whatever reason, you don't like/can't declare `display:block`, you could go with `vertical-align:top` instead.)

Comment: the vertical-align:top works perfectly....display:block worked but it didn't in firefox...thanks :)